# Change decimal numbers in variable editor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, double, decimal

Suppose that we have this code:

```
a = pi;
b = pi+2;
c = pi*2.2
out = [a b c]
```

returns:

```
out =

    3.1416    5.1416    6.9115
```

I want this output (without rounding values to two decimal):

```
out =

    3.14    5.14    6.91
```

I don't want print these values. I want see them with 2 decimals here:
[image]

Comment: Just for display purposes or do you want to actually round off the numbers?

Comment: @Dan. Yes that's true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `format bank` to get 2 decimal displayed. More details about the `format` function in the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html).

If you want to change how the variables are displayed in the variable editor, have a look at [this page of the documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/set-workspace-and-variable-preferences.html#f10-36981).

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will print values with 2 decimal. These isn't any change in `out` window as i displayed above.

Comment: Are you talking about the variable editor? See my edited answer.

Comment: how to do that if we don't want to depend on matlab format options? what if 3 decimals are needed?

Comment: @ironzionlion you can't. You have to go with the formatting options supported by the `format` function in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to use the first 2 decimals, you can add this line to your previous code:

```
out(:) = str2num(sprintf('%6.2f',out(:))); % 2 = number of decimals
```

This is not a beautiful solution but it truncates your values to the 2nd decimal and stores it erasing the following decimals. You will still have some zeros at the end (till you fill the selected format for your variable editor as explained [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30096789/3252535)).

Comment: there are more efficient ways to round numbers to a given precision, Try that : `round2prec = @(vin,prec) round( vin * 10^prec ) / 10^prec;` then type `round2prec([0:3]/pi,2)` in the console to see an example ;-)

Comment: @Hoki Are you aware of the second input of `round(X,N)`? ;) So `round( vin * 10^prec ) / 10^prec` = `round( vin, prec)`

Comment: @thewaywewalk ... haaa, I see on the online doc that Matlab have upped their game. This functionality doesn't exist yet on my R2013a, so I had to do my own way back (_I did that since matlab 5 actually_). But thanks, it's good to know :-)

Comment: @Hoki ah alright, I didn't remembered that it was such a new feature, but now that you say it I think I've used your workaround as well in the past.